How do i resolve nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting
Each time i try running my server using npm start, i keeping getting [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting
My serving is not runningI need help with keeping my server running
please note/ i have express, cors, cookie-parser, bcrypt, mysql, jsonwebtoken installed.

Welcome to StackExchange.  In order for us to be able to troubleshoot your issue, you need to provide more details.  Which OS, which npm version, etc.
